# mongodb-prebuilt hidden directory in my Mac home dir

Tags: mac, mongodb

I am cleaning up my mac to free up spaces and I found this `.mongodb-prebuilt` in my `/Users/username` directory. I did not know what installed this folder.

I had installed these mongo related apps previously:

- mongodb through brew
- Robo3t mongodb client
- Compass mongodb client

Anybody knows what created this directory and can I safely delete it?

Comment: It looks like this is related to the [`mongodb-prebuilt`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-prebuilt) npm package, which I don't believe is used by any of the apps you suggested. Perhaps you installed via `npm` or another application that includes this as a dependency?

Comment: perhaps so. I almost *always* installed my packages using `npm`